# Black dashes when scrolling on webpages. Firefox 13.10

Tags: 13.10, firefox, visual-artifacts

On Firefox with Ubuntu 13.10, and Cinnamon desktop I get dashes appearing on webpages when I scroll. See screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas about what this is and how to get rid of it would be appreciated.

It doesn't happen every time I open a webpage, only sometimes.

Comment: I have the exact same issue 2 computers with the same setup however the only difference is one has the HD3000 the other has the HD4600, the HD4600 has the issue, plenty of ram default zoom and no smooth scroll.
Still not been able to find a fix. Is anyone still having the issue???

Comment: Your last edit is worthy of being an answer. I suggest posting it as an answer for the benefit of others who I'm sure are having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using an Intel graphics chip. The current driver has [a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68410) causing exactly that. It has been fixed in the development version.

As a workaround until the fix is live, it was suggested that disabling **Smooth scrolling** in Firefox [helps with the issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388069/firefox-black-artifacts-on-optimus-when-on-ac-power).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - turning smooth scrolling off doesn't seem to help though. The cpu is an Inetl i7-4500, with a HD 4400 haswell integrated GPU. In the bug report you mentioned it said that it doesnt happen in chrome, so I'll just use that in the meantime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating the intel drivers using the graphics installer from the Intel Open Source Technology Centre seems to have helped with this problem.

Get it here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.4-linux

and run in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) with:

```
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Dashes still appear on occasion, but seem to be much less persistent